# Python selenium, how can i delete an element?

Tags: javascript, python, selenium

I've been trying the last hour to delete an element by without any success. And the element can only be reached via class name.
I've tried:

```
js = "var aa=document.getElementsByClassName('classname')[0];aa.parentNode.removeChild(aa)"
driver.execute_script(js)
```

I get error that parentNode is undefined.

So what the best way to delete an element using Selenium?

Comment: You don't need to call `parentNode`, just `aa.remove()`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

getElementByClassName is not a method on `document`. You'll want to use

```
getElementsByClassName('classname')[0]...
```

but only if you're sure it's the only one with that class.

Comment: oh thanks i edited it as well, yet the queation remains as to how to delete an element :)

Comment: Your method should work. If .parentNode is undefined, then aa isn't a node (or is the body tag or something). did you add the `[0]`?

Comment: i did, then added the 'to be removed object' and now it works, thanks for the help!

Answer (score 51):

I do not know of a Selenium method that is designed specifically to remove elements. However, you can do it with:

```
element = driver.find_element_by_class_name('classname')
driver.execute_script("""
var element = arguments[0];
element.parentNode.removeChild(element);
""", element)
```

`find_element_by_class_name` will raise an exception if the element does not exist. So you don't have to test whether `element` is set to a sensible value. If the method returns, then it is set. Then you pass the element back to `execute_script`. The arguments passed to `execute_script` in Python appear in JavaScript as the `arguments` object. (It's the same as the `arguments` object that you normally get with any JavaScript function. Behind the scenes Selenium wraps the JavaScript code in an anonymous function.)

Or you can use a solution that relies on JavaScript to find the element:

```
driver.execute_script("""
var element = document.querySelector(".classname");
if (element)
    element.parentNode.removeChild(element);
""")
```

This solution is **much better** if you happen to be using a remote server to run your test (like Sauce Labs, or BrowserStack). There's a non-negligible cost to communications between the Selenium client and the server.

Comment: You don't need to call `parentNode`, just `element.remove()`.

Answer (score 3):

Thanks for the input Louis. I built the following python function that uses the JavaScript you suggested:

```
def excludeTagFromWebDriver(driver : WebDriver, selector : str):
    i = 0
    soup = BeautifulSoup(driver.page_source, 'html.parser') # Parsing content using beautifulsoup
    while soup.find(selector):
        # print(soup.find(selector))
        js = """
            var element = document.querySelector(""" + "'" + selector + "'" + """);
            if (element)
                element.parentNode.removeChild(element);
            """
        driver.execute_script(js)
        soup = BeautifulSoup(driver.page_source, 'html.parser') # Parsing content using beautifulsoup
        i += 1
        # print('Removed tag with selector ' + "'" + selector + "'" + ' with nr: ', i)
    print('Removed ' + str(i) + ' tags with the selector ' + "'" + selector + "'" + " and all it's children tags.")
    return driver

driver = excludeTagFromWebDriver(driver,"sup")
```

Comment: You don't need to call `parentNode`, just `element.remove()`.