# Python Selenium - How to Extract/Exclude specific tags or elements in forum posts?

Tags: python, selenium

I have built a web crawler for a forum game in which players use specific keywords in [b] bold [/b] tags to issue their commands. The bot's job is to traverse through the thread and keep a record of all player's commands, however I'm running into a problem where if player A quotes a post from player B, the bot reads the command of player B in the quote and updates the table for player A.

I have found the specific class name of the quote box, but I cannot figure out how to remove the class from the entire post body.

I tried converting the post to text using the get_attribute('innerHTML') and successfully removed it using regex, however the code I wrote to extract the bold tags (find_attribute_by_tag_name) becomes invalid.

I have two questions for the geniuses that post here:

1. Is there a way I can delete a specific element from the post body? I searched throughout google and could not find a working solution
2. Otherwise, is there a way I can convert the HTML I get from get_attribute('innerHTML') back to an element?

> ```
> def ScrapPosts( driver ):
>   posts=driver.find_elements_by_class_name("postdetails")
>   print("Total number of posts on this page:", len(posts))
>   for post in posts:
>       #print("username:",post.find_element_by_tag_name("Strong").text)
>       username=post.find_element_by_tag_name("Strong").text.upper()
>
>
>       #remove the quote boxes before sending to check command?
>       post_txt=post.find_element_by_class_name("content")
>       CheckCommand(post_txt, username)
> ```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. Selenium doesn't have a built in method for deleting elements. However, you can execute some javascript code that can remove the quote box elements. See related question at: https://stackoverflow.com/a/22519967/7880461

This code will delete all elements with the class name quoteBox which I think would work for you if you just change the class name.

```
    driver.execute_script('''
        var element = document.getElementsByClassName("quoteBox"), index;
        for (index = element.length - 1; index >= 0; index--) {
            element[index].parentNode.removeChild(element[index]);
        }
    ''')
```

2. Same answer- no built in way of doing that but you can use javascript. This approach would probably a lot more complicated than the first one.

Comment: Thanks, this worked great. One thing to keep in mind when running this script is that it will remove all elements with the quote class from the entire web scrap. The script can't be called directly on a single element such as a post, however for my purposes this works fine.