# Scraping ALL of Rotten Tomatoes audience reviews for a given movie

Tags: python, web-scraping, url, rotten-tomatoes

I'm trying to scrape the all audience reviews for a given movie on Rotten Tomatoes. Each review page shows 20 reviews and has a button "LOAD MORE" in order to show the next 20 reviews, and so on. See, for instance, https://www.rottentomatoes.com/m/inception/reviews?type=user&intcmp=rt-scorecard_audience-score-reviews

I can use selenium to click through the "LOAD MORE" button until all reviews are loaded, then extract the information from all reviews. This strategy works fine for movies that have a reasonable amount of reviews.

However when the movie has a large number of audience reviews, it becomes problematic because the page takes time to load after a certain amount of clicks and the script ends up crashing. Since the reviews are listed in reverse chronological order, this makes it difficult to reach the very early reviews.

Does anyone know if there's a way of sorting through the audience reviews directly from the url, e.g. to sort reviews in chronological order so the earliest reviews would appear first?

Any other suggestion to solve that issue would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Use the Rotten Tomatoes API: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14172735/how-to-request-movie-data-from-rotten-tomatoes-using-their-json-api

Comment: Thanks, but as far as I understand the API only provides access to individual critic reviews, not individual audience reviews. See https://developer.fandango.com/rotten_tomatoes

Comment: We can't help you debug why your script is crashing, if you don't provide a [MCVE] that demonstrates the problem.

Answer (score 2):

You can use their review api to load the reviews, for example for the movie you posted, the first page is

`https://www.rottentomatoes.com/napi/movie/afbf1c81-1bfe-3996-9cbc-2e1be23d1f61/reviews/user`

The hash after /movie/ in the URL is the ID of the movie which you can extract from the movie page.

The API returns the data in JSON format, there is attribute `pageInfo` with additional attributes `hasNextPage` and `endCursor`. If there are more reviews available then `hasNextPage` is true and you can use `endCursor` to use as a `after` parameter in the URL. For the above URL the next page would be

`https://www.rottentomatoes.com/napi/movie/afbf1c81-1bfe-3996-9cbc-2e1be23d1f61/reviews/user?after=eyJyZWFsbV91c2VySWQiOiJSVF80ZmZlODRmOC04ZTA1LTQ0YTktYjhiOC04NmI3NmVhMGJjYmUiLCJlbXNJZCI6ImFmYmYxYzgxLTFiZmUtMzk5Ni05Y2JjLTJlMWJlMjNkMWY2MSIsImVtc0lkX2hhc1Jldmlld0lzVmlzaWJsZSI6ImFmYmYxYzgxLTFiZmUtMzk5Ni05Y2JjLTJlMWJlMjNkMWY2MV9UIiwiY3JlYXRlRGF0ZSI6IjIwMjMtMTAtMTZUMTY6Mzc6NTkuMTU4WiJ9`

You can use simple python requests to get the reviews instead of selenium, this will make your script more efficient and will take very less time as compared to selenium.

Also, you can use [scrapy](https://scrapy.org/) for web crawling.

Answer (score 0):

You could probably delete the elements as you scrape them to avoid the browser page running out of memory. There are some methods here-
[Python selenium, how can i delete an element?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22515012/python-selenium-how-can-i-delete-an-element).